# How Use Google earth in WPF without WebBrowser & JavaScript

Tags: wpf, multi-touch, google-earth

I want to use Google Earth to Create a GIS map.
I using WPF & *MultiTouch Events* for Map Control and not define ManipulationDelta on WebBrowser Control. Because not use WebBrowser & JavaScript for Map Control.

How can I use Google earth in WPF without WebBrowser & JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JSON GMAP API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html) directly if you want. Have a look at [this project too](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/), may be you find it useful.